# How to convert Strings and handle Variables in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida

By open the Pseudocode View in IDA Pro, i've getting following result:

```
char *v39; // [esp+16Ch] [ebp-15Ch]
v39 = aReload;
Arguments[1] = v39;
_execv(FileName, (const char *const *)Arguments);
```

How i can convert the Strings directly from the assembly data source:

```
.data:005D8C98 aReload         db '/reload',0          ; ...
```

directly to the pseudo code like:

```
Arguments[1] = "/reload";
_execv(FileName, (const char *const *)Arguments);
```

I rarely use IDA, but there was once a setting or key combination that I forgot to change this behavior.

How can I make the pseudocode more compact so that it is easier to read, especially with large methods?